# Heroku rails error trying to bring up console - sh: rails: not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, console

Trying to run the Heroku console but I am getting this following:

```
heroku run console
Running console attached to terminal... up, run.1
sh: console: not found
```

`$ heroku run bash` works but I seem to get a (green) bash prompt - "`~ $`" not a rails console!  Can I get into the console from here?

fyi
`git push heroku v311

Everything up-to-date`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first error is thrown simply because the `console` command doesn't exist. I personally have never meet a command called *console* in my life.

The syntax is `heroku run the_command_i_want_to_run`. For example: `heroku run irb` or `heroku run bash`.

The second error: There's no Rakefile in your project root. Since `heroku run rails console` say that Rails wasn't found, my guess is that your project wasn't (well) deployed.
Make sure you've done `git push heroku`.
You may also need to check the logs: `heroku logs`.

Answer (score 3):

a guess:

`heroku run rails console`

Comment: Corrected my question, title and reason.

Comment: Gives me:  `Running rails console attached to terminal... up, run.1
sh: rails: not found`

Answer (score 3):

If you're on the Bamboo stack (older stack than Cedar), try:

```
heroku run script/rails console
```

This works for me and is the command recommended in [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/console-bamboo).

Answer (score 0):

I got confused by this too.

It's just

```
$ heroku run console
```

Comment: i.e. `heroku run console
Running console attached to terminal... up, run.1
sh: console: not found`

Comment: what happens when you type `$ heroku -v` ... are you running the most up to date version of the heroku gem? Mine works fine. I'm running v2.25.0

Comment: Run `heroku run bash` and then `ls`. This should print the contents of your app directory. Make sure it is not empty, apparently there are some quirks with the initial deploy process. If the folder is empty, try destroying and redeploying the app, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

heroku run -a my-app script/rails console

Reference: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/console-bamboo